# How to read data from .idi file?

Tags: php, readfile, password-protection, php-ziparchive

I have a .IDI file and need to read data from using PHP , it is also password-protected , and I have the password already.

My Question is how to read data from within this file .Also this file is something like a zip archive as I know it contains a .txt file inside it .

I tried to access it as a zip file but I cannot extract what is inside .
Any suggestions on how to solve this or even on what this extesion is ?
Thank you

Comment: I see you tagged ``ZipArchive``, did you try using it at all to open the file?